# CASE statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some trouble here.  I'm not extremely fluent in SQL Server and I have this code in the WHERE clause of a SQL string:

```
[Get_Next_Status] = 'Closed' AND
(([Status] = 'No Error' AND [LiveAndPended] = 'Live' 
AND [Audit Date] Between @StDate And @EnDate)
OR (([Status] = 'No Error' AND [LiveAndPended] = 'Pended' 
AND CASE WHEN CP_DedicatedReleaserDate IS NULL THEN (
[Audit Date] Between @StDate And @EnDate) 
ELSE (CP_DedicatedReleaserDate Between @StDate And @EnDate) END)
OR ([Status] IN ('Financial','Processing') 
AND CP_DedicatedReleaserDate Between @StDate And @EnDate))
```

It doesn't seem to like that CASE statement.  Can someone help me correct it?

Comment: format your code man! it's all over the map.

Comment: `case` does not work like this. You can't switch condition in a `case`

Comment: post your *full* query, formatted please

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, conditions cannot be the result of a `case`.  In this situation, you don't need `case` at all, `coalesce()` will work fine:

```
WHERE Get_Next_Status = 'Closed' AND
      (([Status] = 'No Error' AND [LiveAndPended] = 'Live' AND
        [Audit Date] Between @StDate And @EnDate
       ) OR
       ([Status] = 'No Error' AND [LiveAndPended] = 'Pended' AND
        COALESCE(CP_DedicatedReleaserDate, [Audit Date]) Between @StDate And @EnDate
       ) OR
       ([Status] IN ('Financial','Processing') AND 
        CP_DedicatedReleaserDate Between @StDate And @EnDate)
      )
```